# Why does this message keep appearing in my output? "(HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false"

Tags: java, android, aide

For this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\n");
        System.out.println("Please enter text");
        String input = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Your text: " + input);
    }
```

Without user input, I immediately get the output:

```
Please enter text
(HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
(HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```

This text continues to appear in pairs in the output at regular intervals.

Why is this text appearing and how do I remove it? I read from other posts that this text shows up in logcat.

I am building a Java application using AIDE (Android IDE) on a Samsung S7.

Comment: is your app, activity or fragment trying to connect a http service? the code you show is not HTTP related.

Comment: I'm building a Java console application (not an Android app), and it does not have anything to do with HTTP. Sorry if my inital post was unclear on this part.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59098728/edit) your question and update it.